# Java date formatting

Tags: java, parsing, date, format

The input string is like mentioned below

> 20110913T100702.631 GMT

The out put needed is in the format like this

> Tuesday, September 13, 2011 17:52:PM

Can you please help me on this. (In this example the input value and the out put value are not connected those are 2 separate values)

Comment: what code have you tried? If you show what code you have tried we can try to help you find what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Have you looked into using SimpleDateFormat? Please first show the fruits of your own efforts so we can better help you.

Comment: Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Comment: 17:52 PM... the format used in the department of redundancy department?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
private String formatDate() throws Exception {
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS Z");
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE', 'MMMMM' 'dd', 'yyyy' 'h:mm:a");
    Date date = inputFormat.parse("20110913T100702.631 GMT ");
    return outputFormat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need class SimpleDateFormat or DateFormat
http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.parse (
    "20110913T100702.631 GMT" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS z" )
).format( 
     DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL , FormatStyle.SHORT )
                      .withLocale( Locale.US )
 )
```

> Tuesday, September 13, 2011 10:07 AM

## ISO 8601

Your input string nearly complies with a format defined as a “basic” version of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The word *basic* means minimizing the use of the separators otherwise used by the more common “expanded” version of the ISO 8601 format.

```
String input = "20110913T100702.631 GMT" ;
```

## Using java.time

The other Answers use the troublesome old legacy date-time classes, now supplanted by the java.time classes.

The java.time classes use many of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So often there is no need to specify a formatting pattern. But this particular *basic* format is not supported by default, so we must specify a formatting pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter fInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS z" );
```

Parse as an `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse ( input, fInput );
```

To generate a string representing the value of the `ZonedDateTime` object in your desired format, you could define a specify formatting pattern. But I suggest you instead let java.time automatically localize for you.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

So…

```
// Generate output string
Locale locale = Locale.US;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH, Locale.ITALY, etc.
DateTimeFormatter fOutput =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime ( FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.SHORT ) // Specify format style of date portion, then time-of-day portion.
                     .withLocale ( locale );
String output = zdt.format ( fOutput );
```

Dump to console.

```
// Dump to console
System.out.println ( "input: " + input );
System.out.println ( "zdt.toString(): " + zdt );
System.out.println ( "output: " + output );
```

See [this code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/0ZMcnB).

> input: 20110913T100702.631 GMT
>
> zdt.toString(): 2011-09-13T10:07:02.631Z[GMT]
>
> output: Tuesday, September 13, 2011 10:07 AM

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).